# Windows 10 System Won't Stay Asleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management

Here's my situation:

1. The only device on my computer which can wake the machine from sleep state is the network card (I need that active because this is a media server which remote display devices need to be able to wake up).
2. The only wake timers present are from a DVR program, SageTV, which uses them to wake up to record shows. The system refuses to stay asleep even when the wake timer is set for some point hours in the future.
3. The application log is filled with pairs of events like the following:

   ```
   Log Name:      System
   Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
   Date:          4/22/2017 1:24:13 AM
   Event ID:      42
   Task Category: (64)
   Level:         Information
   Keywords:      (1024),(4)
   User:          N/A
   Computer:      Colossus
   Description:
   The system is entering sleep.
   Sleep Reason: System Idle
   Event Xml:
   <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
     <System>
       <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
       <EventID>42</EventID>
       <Version>3</Version>
       <Level>4</Level>
       <Task>64</Task>
       <Opcode>0</Opcode>
       <Keywords>0x8000000000000404</Keywords>
       <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-04-22T08:24:13.738158400Z" />
       <EventRecordID>1973</EventRecordID>
       <Correlation />
       <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="6676" />
       <Channel>System</Channel>
       <Computer>Colossus</Computer>
       <Security />
     </System>
     <EventData>
       <Data Name="TargetState">4</Data>
       <Data Name="EffectiveState">5</Data>
       <Data Name="Reason">7</Data>
       <Data Name="Flags">0</Data>
       <Data Name="TransitionsToOn">24</Data>
     </EventData>
   </Event>
   ```

followed shortly thereafter by:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          4/22/2017 1:24:15 AM
Event ID:      107
Task Category: (102)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (1024),(64),(4)
User:          N/A
Computer:      Colossus
Description:
The system has resumed from sleep.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
    <EventID>107</EventID>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>102</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000444</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-04-22T08:24:15.736975500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1974</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="6676" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Colossus</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="TargetState">4</Data>
    <Data Name="EffectiveState">5</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeFromState">4</Data>
    <Data Name="ProgrammedWakeTimeAc">2017-04-22T18:58:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="ProgrammedWakeTimeDc">2017-04-22T18:58:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeRequesterTypeAc">1</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeRequesterTypeDc">1</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

4. `powercfg /lastwake` shows no events as having woken up the machine.

So the system is trying to go to sleep...but something is waking it up 2 seconds later.

What is going on, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same thing. It remains in sleep if not connected to the Internet, so I looked at my Network Adapter via the device manager and changed "Wake on Pattern Match" to disabled and this fixed it for me.